# After receiving access token I cannot retrieve any data from oauth.reddit.com Java.IO.FileNotFoundExceeption

Tags: java, android, api, oauth, reddit

I've been going nuts with this and changed every variable I can. Starting simply and sending only the minimum required headers to base64 encoding the token, sending credentials, using GET and POST. Code has become a little messy but I'm hoping someone can help out with this issue. I'm using script application to access the reddit api with android studio / java.

```java
String f = Base64.encodeToString(new String(token).getBytes(),0);
URL connection2 = new URL(oauthURL+"/me");

HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)connection2.openConnection();
http.setRequestMethod("POST");
http.setDoOutput(true);

http.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "bearer "+token);

Map<String,String> arguments = new HashMap<>();
//     arguments.put("grant_type", "password");
//     arguments.put("username", redditUser);
//     arguments.put("password", redditPass);
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("&");
for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : arguments.entrySet()) {
  sj.add(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "="
        + URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
}
byte[] out = sj.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
int length = out.length;

http.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(length);

http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
http.connect();

try(OutputStream os = http.getOutputStream()) {
  os.write(out);
}

InputStream is = http.getInputStream();
System.out.println(http.getContentType());
```

My last output was:

```
I/System.out: >>>>> START <<<<<
I/System.out: {"access_token": "REMOVED", "token_type": "bearer", "expires_in": 86400, "scope": "*"}
I/System.out: REMOVED:bearer:86400:*
I/System.out: >>>>>> END <<<<<
I/System.out: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me
```

As you can see I'm receiving the access token just fine using similar code as above. I'm obviously missing something but got to thinking it could be one of too many things, like capatilization on Authorization header or using under score or dash on User-Agent etc.

Answer (score 0):

So this was a frustration but I've realised calling http.connect() is unnecessary and the code was giving me "Already Connected" when I initiated the input stream. Simple fix but I thought a connection needed to be made first. So after getting my token from a previous method I've flushed/closed/disconnected "connection" and "http". Then this following code has worked, also calling getContentType would throw an "Already Connected" error.

```
            try {
                connection = new URL(oauthURL+"/api/v1/me").openConnection();
                http = (HttpsURLConnection)connection;
                http.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
                http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "bearer "+token);

                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

                Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
                String res = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";

                System.out.println(res);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {System.out.println(e);}
```